# Best scoring performances in an NBA finals loss

Tags: basketball, nba, postseason

LeBron James of the Cleveland Cavaliers scored 51 points in a losing effort against the Golden State Warriors in game 1 of 2017 - 2018 NBA finals. That made James the 6th player ever to score 50+ points in the NBA finals, but he also became the first person in that list to lose the game.

What are the top 5 scoring performances in the NBA finals that resulted in a loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Basketball Reference's Player Game Finder with the following [search criteria](https://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/pgl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=game&year_min=1964&year_max=2019&is_playoffs=Y&round_id=fin&game_result=L&age_min=0&age_max=99&season_start=1&season_end=-1&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&order_by=pts):

> In a single game, from 1964 to 2019, in the playoffs, round is Finals, team lost game, sorted by descending Points

The top 5 scoring performances in the NBA finals that resulted in a loss are:

1) LeBron James - [51 points](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201805310GSW.html), Game 1, 2018 NBA Finals (Cavaliers at Warriors)

2) Stephen Curry - [47 points](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201906050GSW.html), Game 3, 2019 NBA Finals (Raptors at Warriors)

T3) Jerry West - [45 points](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/196604220LAL.html), Game 4, 1966 NBA Finals (Celtics at Lakers)

T3)  Jerry West - [45 points](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/196504190BOS.html), Game 2, 1965 NBA Finals (Lakers at Celtics)

T5) LeBron James - [44 points](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201506040GSW.html), Game 1, 2015 NBA Finals (Cavaliers at Warriors)

T5) Shaquille O'Neal - [44 points](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/200106060LAL.html), Game 1, 2001 NBA Finals (76ers at Lakers)

T5) Michael Jordan - [44 points](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/199306130CHI.html), Game 3, 1993 NBA Finals (Suns at Bulls)

T5) Rick Barry - [44 points](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/196704240SFW.html), Game 6, 1967 NBA Finals (76ers at Warriors)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please indicate the teams playing and I will accept your answer

Comment: @alamoot Teams have been added

Answer (score 0):

**#1. 63 points: [Michael Jordan](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jordami01.html) & Chicago Bulls**

- April 20, 1986 - Eastern Conference first round; Chicago Bulls Vs. Boston Celtics. [Boston won: 135 - 131.](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/198604200BOS.html)

**#2. 61 points - [Ray Allen](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/allenra02.html) & Boston Celtics**

- April 30, 2009 - Eastern Conference First Round; Boston Celtics Vs. Chicago Bulls. [Chicago won: 128 - 127](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/200904300CHI.html)

**#3.1 51 points - [Russell Westbrook](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/w/westbru01.html) & Oklahoma Thunder**

- April 19, 2017 - Western Conference Quarter Finals; Oklahoma Thunder Vs. Houston Rockets. [Houston won: 115 - 111](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201704190HOU.html)

**#3.2 51 points - [LeBron James](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html) & Cleveland Cavaliers**

- May 31, 2018 - NBA Finals; Cleveland Cavaliers Vs. Golden State Warriors. [Golden State won: 124 - 114](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201805310GSW.html)

**#4.1 50 points -  [Bill Cunningham](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/cunnibi01.html) & Philadelphia 76ers**

- April 1, 1970 - Eastern Division Semi Finals; Philadelphia 76ers Vs.  Milwaukee Bucks. [Milwaukee won: 118 - 111](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/197004010PHI.html)

**#4.2 50 points -  [Michael Jordan](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jordami01.html) & Chicago Bulls**

- May 5 1989 - Eastern Conference First Round; Chicago Bulls Vs. Cleveland Cavaliers. [Cleveland won: 108 - 105](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/198905050CHI.html)

**#4.3 50 points -  [Kobe Bryant](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/bryanko01.html) & Los Angeles Lakers**

- May 4, 2006 - Western Conference First Round; Los Angeles Lakers Vs. Phoenix Suns. [Phoenix won: 126 - 118](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/200605040LAL.html)

**Additional Reference:** 
[List of National Basketball Association single-game playoff scoring leaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_National_Basketball_Association_single-game_playoff_scoring_leaders)

Comment: Your response seems to be answering highest points scored in a loss in any playoff games, which is not exactly what I asked. My question is targeting exactly the NBA finals.